# PHP Fatal error: Class 'SoapClient' not found in /home/ec2-user

Tags: php, amazon-ec2

There are a number of similar topics, however I have not been able to solve this problem.  When I run a php script on an EC2 Linux (Amazon Linux AMI 2014.03.1) I get the above error.

When I do a system find I only can locate one php.ini file.  It is located in /etc/php.ini.  From reading elsewhere I should not alter this file but create my own .ini file in /etc/php.d.  Therefore I have created a file called myphp.ini with the following line of code at the top.

extension=php_soap.dll
or
extension=php_soap.so

now when I attempt to run the php script I get the following:
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/php_soap.dll' - /usr/lib64/php/modules/php_soap.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
(.. same for both php_soap.so and dll)

Not quite sure what to do from here, just looking for the easiest way to enable SOAP.  I have two linux installations that are similar, both have the same problem (ie it is not specific to EC2).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before enabling it, you should install it...

For example, on Debian based distro it would be `sudo apt-get install php-soap` (also this will create required ini file for extension)

Comment: OK, that makes sense.  For me is was yum install php-soap.

Comment: On one of the AWS servers I had to do "sudo yum install php55-soap" and also "apachectl graceful" to reboot PHP

Comment: I had to do it again and I used "sudo yum install php56-soap" and "apachectl graceful"